# Place for declaring interface

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Assume a program on `C#`(or any other language that has an abstraction of *interface*) where first part (A) and second part (B) depend on the third part (C). For example  assume Visual Studio solution with three projects where class `ClassA` in project A and `ClassB` in project B depends on instance of `ClassC` in project C. I want to separate interface from implementation, so that I create interface `IClassC` and use it in `ClassA` and `ClassB`. In which project I should declare the interface `IClassC`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of cases it would be in project C, but what if you want assembly is plugin-able, it means you can change the implementation of interface C. And you don't want to re-build project A and B each time when you change code in project C.

With this case you need to apply [DIP principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) to inverse dependency, so interface C should be in new project call IC. The dependency will change from:

```
A -> C
B -> C
```

To:

```
C -> IC
A -> IC
B -> IC
```

So with this way when you change code in C or replace C with C', it also does not affect to A and B.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like ProjectC doesn't depend on ProjectA or ProjectB, but clearly needs to know about the interface (so that the class can implement it). Therefore it *has* to be in ProjectC or some other project that every project depends on. (You *could* have a separate project just for the interfaces, but I've rarely found that to be useful.)

Answer (score 1):

In Project C, or a separate interface project Project I

Answer (score 0):

You can declare it in the ClassC project, this would be fine from a referencing point of view.

You could also place it in its own interfaces project, which would enable you to reference the interface separately in, for example, test projects.